# App getting stuck after click on close button of window

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am creating one window in extjs 3. In window I have a panel in which I am including item with `afterrender`. I place some button on window including **cancle.** after clicking on window close button or cancel buttonMy app getting stuck. What will be the possible reason.

My Panel Code :

```
{
xtype: 'panel',
title : "Records",
bodyStyle: 'background: #dfe8f6;border:#dfe8f6;',
id:'AlteredRecord',
region: 'center',
layout:{
    type: 'vbox',
    pack: 'start',
    align: 'stretch'
},
items:[],
listeners:{
    afterrender: function(){
        debugger;
        var grid = Ext.getCmp('GRID');
        var record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
        var actionRecItemsLen = record.length;
        var multirfchelper = Ext.getCmp('multirfchelper');
        var rec = Ext.getCmp('AlteredRecord');
        var recItem = rec.items.items;
        var clsName = new Recordrfc(),
        for(var i=0;i<actionRecItemsLen; i++){
                var sub = record[i].data.USUB;
                var clsName = new Recordrfc();
                recItem.push(clsName);
                this.doLayout();
            }
    }
},
    }
```

Comment: Post some code  to have a look

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma I update my question. Code for panel I mentioned.

Comment: For item addition you are doing layout update it is not good pracitse  do this.doLayout() after the for loop.

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma Yes, I removed but still no luck. When I commenting code of afterrender then window is closing perfectly but when I place afterrender on close I is getting stuck.  Is there any other way by which I can place item in panel.

Comment: Also I noticed if I remove ` recItem.push(clsName);` this line and instead of that I am using `panel.add(clsName)` then it is fine. But in this case only one record is adding.